# Open file in new browser tab by input file value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open the file in a new browser tab for previewing.

```
<input id="myinput" type="file" onchange="oninputfileselected(this);"/>
```

```js
function oninputfileselected(obj) {
  var inputfile = document.getElementById($(obj).attr('id'));
  console.log(inputfile.files);
}
```

The `console` output I get doesn't contain any local path for me to open a new tab. I am not sure if there is another way to do this? Thank you

Comment: There won't be any local path available in JS for a file selected through a file control. To achieve what you need you would need to use a FileReader and output its content to a new window.

Comment: You cannot (thankfully) read the local file system using Javascript. Sounds like a job for `FileReader` and `data:`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only approach I can think of would be to use `FileReader` to read the data in the file, then generate a `data:` scheme URL from it, then open that URL with `window.open`.

Comment: oh great ! thx to your suggestion, i just google FileReader example and try in my script , it work ! thx !